# form is not ended properly inside the table that causes update method

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Here is my code, i have wasted lot of time on this but still did not get the answer.Form ended in the same row where it started and because of this submit method is not adding the checkbox values in database.please help?

```
< table>
  <% pos = 0%>
  <% @accounts.each do |myacc| %>
    <% if @accounts.length  == pos +1 %>
      <tr class="last">
    <% else%>
      <tr>
    <% end %> <!-- end of if tag -->
    <td class="position"><%= pos += 1%>.</td>
    <td ><%= myacc.name %>< /td>
    < % form_for(:account,:html =>{:method =>:put,:id =>"editAccountForm_"+pos.to_s,:multipart => true}) do|f|%>
      <td>
        <% if myacc.place_matching == "1" %>
          <input type="checkbox" id=place_matching value=1 checked="checked"  />
        <% else %> 
          <input type="checkbox" id=place_matching value=0  />
        <% end %> <!-- end of if tag -->                                                 
      </td>
      <td> 
        <% if myacc.data_pulling == "1" %>
          <input type="checkbox" id="data_pulling" value=1 checked="checked" />
        <% else %> 
          <input type="checkbox"  id="data_pulling"  value=0  />
        <% end %> <!-- end of if tag -->
      </td>
      <td>
        <a class="gray-button gray-whitebg" href="#" onclick="getElementById('editAccountForm_<%= pos%>').submit();return false;" />ADD</a>
      </td>
    <% end %> <!-- end of form tag -->
    </tr>
  <% end %> 
</table>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please paste your complete form..

please take you form out from your table..

hope this will help

Comment: This is not an answer. Please use comments for requests

Comment: @yule. there was an miscommunication. I think you have seen my answer when i was updating my answer.

Answer (score 0):

In rails 3 you always have to use `<%= %>` form, also for blocks.
So write

```
<%= form_for ...
```

I see you use the `form_for`, but then not use `f` at all. Why not use `f.check_box` ? See [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html).
Or use `form_tag` and then use `check_box_tag`. See [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html).

You should be using more of the helpers rails gives you.